# Send login details with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to get this bit of code to pause/unpause my XBMC Player

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseUrl+playPause);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
Debug.WriteLine(resStream);
```

And I need to send my login data with it, lets say its `MyUsername` and `SuperPassword`.

How would I add that data intp the request? I tried `request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "MyUsername SuperPassword");` but I still get the 401 error from it.

EDIT: Nevermind, i figured it out

```
String username = "MyUsername";
String password = "SuperPassword";
String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a awesome post about Send login details with HttpWebRequest and the link is [post link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx) 
if You feel brother then you can also try one my Best solve this by using webClient class. example:

```
var url = @"..."; 
            var mybar= new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            mybar.Add("username", "username");
            mybar.Add("password", "password");
            var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
            var data = client.UploadValues(url, mybar);
            var res = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
            Console.WriteLine(res);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: May it's help you .i wish you can try